# PHP will not Echo

Tags: php

I've tried to look into why this isn't echoing but every result the persons trying use php on an html page so this is why I'm here asking.

I have 3 php files, a login file, a global config file, and a theme file.
The login page echo's the login script but it connects to the global file. The global file connects to the theme file and the db config file. The theme file is a simple table.

Here's my files

```
<?
include('../tools/global.php');



switch($_POST[act]){

case "setlogin":
set($login);
break;

case "refresh":
refresh();
break;

case "logout":
lout();
break;

default:
login($mes);
break;
}

function login($mes){


if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])){
$out[body]="<br />
<center>
<table width='90%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' bgcolor='#BDBDBD'>
<tr bgcolor='##ff80ff'>
<td width='100%' valign='center' align='left' colspan='2' background='#BDBDBD'>
<strong>Login</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor='#BDBDBD'>
<td width='100%' valign='center' align='left'><center>
<b>You are already logged in! Would you like to <a href='http://www.fivedesignguys.com/dir/panel/login.php?act=refresh&type=logout'>Logout?</a></center></td></tr>
</table>
</center><br /><br /><br /><br />";

}else{

$out[body]="
<br />
<center>
<table width='400' border='0' cellspacing='1' bgcolor='#BDBDBD' cellpadding='1'>
<form method='post'>
<tr bgcolor='$config[altcolor]'>
<td background='#BDBDBD' width='100%' valign='center' align='left' colspan='2'>
<strong>Login</strong>";
```

It continues but I know it's going to echo me the first option,

Heres the global php file

```
<?php

include('../theme/default.php');
include('config.php');

?>
```

and finally the default.php theme file

```
<table border='0'>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'>
<center>bar</center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='10%'>
hey<br>hey<br>
</td>
<td>
hello
<?php

echo $out[body];
?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

as you can tell I want it to echo $out[body] but it doesn't want to. Yes all the files are PHP but this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: First of all it has to be `$out["body"]` and then it is not a global variable. Its a variable defined inside your function and hence you cannot echo it outside just like that. Either return the variable to main control or make it global

Comment: Array should be like $out['body'] instead of $out[body]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$out` array is not a global, so it can't be read outside the `login()` function.

You should declare the array as global and read a bit about [globals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: I changed the variable to $body so setting `global $body;` didn't work. Would I have to wrap it in a function and then would it be able to be accessed for example a register.php page?